# Creating Web Service Client from WSDL that requires SSL certificate

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, ssl, wsdl

I need to create a Web Service Client using Apache CXF 2.x in Eclipse from the following WSDL:

https://test.timbrado.com.mx/cfdi/wstimbrado.asmx?WSDL

The problem is that the web service requires a SSL certificate to work properly.

I already installed the certificate in my machine, added the certificate to the Java keystore (cacerts) located in ${jdk_home}/jre/lib/security/, but I don't know how to install this certificate in eclipse.

When trying to create the Web Service Client, I write the WSDL's URL and get the following error:

> "The service definition selected is invalid"

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the WSDL manually and then generate the web service off of the downloaded file.

Comment: I have the same problem, but can't download the WSDL because it requires the SSL certificate to be downloaded.

Comment: @GiovanniP you can try installing the cert in your browser and then downloading it, or simply have the folks you're connecting to send you the WSDL directly.

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't know browsers supported installation of certificates. Thanks.